# Multiple Group Checkboxes Require At least 1 from Each Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/vuw24bzj/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length > 0;
        if(!checked) {
            alert("You must check either full time or part time.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I have multiple check boxes on two different input areas as seen in js.fiddle. The code I currently have above only provides one box in the whole page to be checked. However, I need it one box from each to be required. Is there a way to do this or a way grabbing input specifically by the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 conditions based on `name` (or add a common class to each type to simplify selector)

```
checked = $(":checkbox[name=days]:checked").length > 0 
            && $(":checkbox[name=employmentType]:checked").length > 0 ;
```